# PHP SoapClient on tcp port 808

Tags: php, web-services, soap

Normally using SOAP over port 80 is simple:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://domain.com/webservice?wsdl');
```

How would you consume the web service over another tcp port?  (Not 80 or 443)

Comment: have you tried `http://domain.com:808/webservice?wsdl` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

`http://domain.com:808/webservice?wsdl`

=>

`$client = new SoapClient('http://domain.com:808/webservice?wsdl');`

Term `:808` indicates port number of an URI, if you omit it, it will use default port number for specified protocol. *(80: for HTTP)*

[RFC 3986:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

> In general, a URI that uses the generic syntax for authority with
> an    empty path should be normalized to a path of "/".  Likewise, an
> explicit ":port", for which the port is empty or the default for the
> scheme, is equivalent to one where the port and its ":" delimiter are
> elided and thus should be removed by scheme-based normalization.  For
> example, the second URI above is the normal form for the "http"
> scheme.

A good overview for URI is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme).

Comment: Thank you. I did try that and it failed, but that's because the vendor had closed 808 by accident without telling me.  Thank you anyway.  This is the correct answer for anyone that has the same question.

Comment: Note that PHP will not allow you to specify port if using HTTPS.